# Fitting a Circle Arc to a Parabola

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0310086.pdf) for a project. In section 2.1 it says an approximate formula for the smooth curve described by the edge of the ski
is y ≈ $x^2/2R_{SC} − d$. Why is the $x^2$ value divided by $2R_{SC}$? I get that they are trying to fit a parabola to a circle of radius $R_{SC}$ and chord length $C$, but I don't understand what geometry they did to divide by $2R_{SC}$. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Write the equation of the circle as $x^2 + (y - (R - d))^2 = R^2$. Divide through by $R^2$ and rewrite everything in terms of the dimensionless quantities $\xi = x/R$, $\eta = y/R$, and $\epsilon = d/R$.

Consider $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ to be small quantities. Expand everything out and drop all second-order terms (like $\epsilon^2$, $\eta\epsilon$, etc.). You should get $y = {x^2\over 2R} - d$.

To spell it out: divide through by $R^2$ in $x^2 + (y - (R - d))^2 = R^2$ to get $$\left({x\over R}\right)^2 + \left({y\over R} - \left(1 - {d\over R}\right)\right)^2 = 1\,.$$ Define the variables I mentioned above: $$\xi^2 + (\eta - (1-\epsilon))^2 = 1\,.$$ Expand everything out: $$\xi^2 + \eta^2 - 2\eta + 2\eta\epsilon + 1 - 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2 = 1\,.$$ Drop $\eta^2$, $\eta\epsilon$, and $\epsilon^2$: $$\xi^2 - 2\eta - 2\epsilon = 0\,.$$ Rearrange as $$\eta = {\xi^2\over 2} - \epsilon\,.$$ Multiply through by $R$ to get $y = {x^2\over 2R} - d$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, why can you drop all second order terms, wouldn't they be more significant to the equation than the first order terms? Also why is your final answer the paper's final answer multiplied by -1?

Comment: Sorry, typo! Fixed in the above. You drop second-order terms because $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ are less than 1, and when you multiply two numbers together that are less than 1, you get something less than either of the two numbers you started with. For example, $(0.01)\times (-0.003) = -0.00003$. The product is smaller in absolute value than either of the small numbers being multiplied.

Comment: I wrote out the derivation above. Let me know if there are any mistakes. Does this answer your question? Basically, I don't think they did any geometry to get this result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is very helpful